# Convert variable string to array 2d

Tags: python-2.7

This is a string.

```
a = "{'id':'1','nama':'try','stok':'try','satuan':'try'},{'id':'2','nama':'asep','stok':'23','satuan':'pcs'}"
```

How to convert it to a 2D array?

Comment: What do you imagine this "2D array" looks like?

Comment: i believe he would like to get a list of list [[],[]]

Comment: i will using it to grid python..

Comment: sorry, i'm new bie in python

Comment: you have to give us all the detail how do you like to get the final result. so detail more your need.

Comment: a list of list of what? :(

Answer (score 0):

This string form very similar to an encoded json string that by few change on this you can load this by json library, python code for converting this value to the 2D array is below:

```
import json
a = "{'id':'1','nama':'try','stok':'try','satuan':'try'},{'id':'2','nama':'a
sep','stok':'23','satuan':'pcs'}"
res = json.loads("[" + a.replace("'", '"') + "]" )
out = []
for row in res:
    out.append([])
    for cell in row:
        out[-1].append( row[cell] )
print "\noutput: " + str( out )

output: [[u'try', u'1', u'try', u'try'], [u'asep', u'2', u'pcs', u'23']]
```

on the output you can see the value in erratic positions you can determine position of values by few changing on the inner for statement.

```
import json
a = "{'id':'1','nama':'try','stok':'try','satuan':'try'},{'id':'2','nama':'a
sep','stok':'23','satuan':'pcs'}"
res = json.loads("[" + a.replace("'", '"') + "]" )
out = []
for row in res:
    out.append([])
    for cell in [ "id", "nama", "stok", "satuan" ]:
        out[-1].append( row[cell] )
print "\noutput: " + str( out )

output: [[u'1', u'try', u'try', u'try'], [u'2', u'asep', u'23', u'pcs']]
```

good luck